# My edits need approval again… AND I can vote for my own edit, giving it half the approval needed

Tags: support, bug

Edit of question:

[Need help implementing DCT Type 4 algorithm](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38908/need-help-implementing-dct-type-4-algorithm)

I edited the question, and then noticed that I was presented with the "your edit will be placed in a review queue" form that low-rep users are greeted with.

That's kind of confusing, considering my 27 dBRep status.

What's more confusing: I could vote on my own edit, and it now only needs another vote to be approved.

Might be related: Once in a while (every week or so), I can't post a comment. The website then shows me red box saying that unregistered users can comment, and I have to reload the page on which I want to comment to make things work.

**EDIT**: Happened again, this time on my own answer, a couple minutes after posting it (when I decided I want to add something to it):

[image: fail]

cancelling and clicking edit again didn't help, reloading the page does.

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that you were logged in, etc? By the look of it, this edit was proposed by an anonymous user. There are no other edits/actions made with respect to that question.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. Especially since, without reloading the page, I could then click on the "edit (1)" link below the question, and approve my own edit...

Comment: Interesting. There is no trace of other edits at all.

Comment: heh. So, what do we do now? I just realized that occasionally, I can't post comments, while I'm logged in, with an error message that "you have to be logged in to post comments" or so. Editing that into my Q.

Comment: I did cross check that IP if it was ever used by you, and indeed it was. This could mean that you are having some issues with your browser, etc. I will ask "techy guys" to have a look into that.

Comment: thanks! If it helps, the commenting problem also happens on other SE sites

Comment: Just happened again on ham.SE, this time I tried reloading the question page and re-did my edit, which worked. Browser has been sending the same cookies everytime, says firefox web dev tools

Comment: Happened again! This time with screenshot; see Q :)